# how to add a time delay after .show jquery

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have a button on my page which when pressed displays a hidden div. Is there a way for me to use jquery .show so that this div (containing text) is shown, appears for a few seconds, say 3 seconds, and then is hidden again without a user havind to re-click the button. (ie. use the .hide jquery function). Below i will attach the appropriate code:

```
<body>

<button  class="info" id="one"> ? </button>

<div class="pop" id="1" style="display: none">
A Careless criminal has dropped a weapon!
</div>

<script>
   $("button#one").click(function () {
    $("div#1").show("slow");
    });
 </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Description

You should use jQuery's `.show()`, `.delay()` and `.hide()` method for that.

**Note:** jQuery `.show()` and `.hide()` uses `.animate()` internally.

Check out the sample the this **[jSFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/8yqtc/)**.

#### Sample

```
$("button#one").click(function () {
    $("div#1").show("slow").delay(3000).hide("slow");
});
```

#### More Information

- [jSFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/8yqtc/)
- [jQuery.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)
- [jQuery.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)
- [jQuery.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)
- [jQuery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, easily, using [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay) and [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide):

```
$('div#1').show('slow').delay(3000).hide('slow');
```

Note that this works because `hide` is an animation function. If you didn't have an animation function and wanted to do something else (e.g. removing with `remove`) you'd have to use a different method, using callbacks and `setTimeout`.